# Facebook JavaScript API Error in Safari: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'b.fbCallID=a.id')

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, safari, typeerror

As of about a week ago (the cutover to OAuth 2.0, I believe), I am getting the following error on page load in Safari when including http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js.

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'b.fbCallID=a.id')
```

My markup and JavaScript are as follows:

```
<fb:login-button scope="email">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>

$(function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '12345',
        cookie: true,
        status: true,
        xfbml: true
    });

    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
          document.cookie = 'access_token=' + response.authResponse.accessToken;
          window.location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

This previously worked fine and is still working as expected in Chrome. Has anyone else seen this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing the `FB.login` call to the following:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        document.cookie = 'access_token=' + response.authResponse.accessToken;
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```